# Solving sets of PDE in Mathematica analytically

Tags: differential-equations

This is a fairly general question. My work often involves trying to see if a set of PDE has any analytical solutions under certain simplification.
I recently realized that manually removing expressions that factor out can make it much easier to find solutions to PDE. This made me realize that might be other tricks that I dont know.

I have been using DSolve and was wondering if there are any tricks or any tutorials on what else I could try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> that might be other tricks that I dont know.

Your question is really very generic and hard to know where to start. But the following are two tricks if that is what you want to call them, that sometimes can help.

### Trick 1

Given a PDE with complicated function for say initial conditions (or BC, etc..), where Mathematica `DSolve` can't solve the pde because of it (since it tries to integrate internally these functions).

You can instead of using the actual function, using a generic $f(x,y)$ function in its place as place holder. This allows Mathematica to quickly find the solution. But in terms of an integral that can't be evaluated yet. But at least you can see the solution and then work on the integrations as separate problem. It is possible to find way to integrate the function on its own and then plug the answer in the solution of the pde.

You can also replace the actual definition of the function in the solution obtained if needed.

Here is an example of wave pde in 2D with very complicated made up initial conditions, that Mathematica seems to hang on.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
pde = D[u[x, y, t], {t, 2}] == D[u[x, y, t], {x, 2}] + D[u[x, y, t], {y, 2}];
bc = {u[x, 0, t] == 0, u[x, 1, t] == 0, u[0, y, t] == 0, u[1, y, t] == 0};
actualFunction = x*y*Sin[Pi*x]*Sin[Pi*y]*Exp[x^2*Sin[x*y]];
ic = {u[x, y, 0] == actualFunction , (D[u[x, y, t], t] /. t -> 0) == 0}
sol = DSolve[{pde, bc, ic}, u[x, y, t], {x, y, t}] /. {K[1] -> n, K[3] -> m}
```

Instead of the above, just change the `ic` line above to

```
ic = {u[x, y, 0] == f[x, y] , (D[u[x, y, t], t] /. t -> 0) == 0}
sol = DSolve[{pde, bc, ic}, u[x, y, t], {x, y, t}] /. {K[1] -> n, K[3] -> m}
```

And now Mathematica instantly gives the answer as

[image: Mathematica graphics]

### Second trick:

Sometimes you can help Mathematica `DSolve` if it can't solve a pde by telling it the solution of the pde is the product of two functions or product of three functions (separation of variables).

Here is an example

```
pde = D[u[x, t], t] == D[u[x, t], {x, 2}] + u[x, t];
DSolve[pde, u[x, t], {x, t}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now assume the solution $u=X(x) T(t)$

```
newsys = (pde /. u -> Function[{x, t}, X[x]*T[t]])
newsys = Assuming[X[x]*T[t] != 0, DivideSides[ newsys, X[x]*T[t]]]
newsys = Collect[newsys, T[t]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now you can solve each ode on its own by assuming each is equal to a constant say $-\lambda$ and then use BC to finish the solutions then obtain a series sum of these products.

I think if you search this site, you'll find such examples of the above.